# What's the point of the Maze in Maze runner?

Tags: the-maze-runner

So at the end of the first Maze Runner movie, it's revealed that

> the kids are being tested so they could monitor their brains and find a cure.

But what does this have to do with a maze specifically? Aren't there thousands of things you can do to achieve the same result?

**Why specifically do you need a maze to achieve this?**

Comment: Because everyone would just be running in a straight line and the book would be very boring.

Comment: Any why even bother running??

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - If I wanted to watch teens standing around doing nothing useful for hours on end, I'd look out of the damn window

Comment: @Valorum - it might be more interesting than watching the Maze Runner movies...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's a meticulous experiment to produce and recollect Brain Patterns during Extreme Situations

The Gladers are already inmune to the Flare since the beginning and what makes them inmune is his brain patterns in the "[Killzone](http://mazerunner.wikia.com/wiki/Killzone)" area, ***specially during extreme stress*** when The Flare seems to infect the subject faster.

> “Out of all those people, only a fraction survived to be here today. I’massuming you’ve figured this out
>   by now, but many of the things that happen to you are solely for the purpose of judging and analyzing your
>   responses. And yet it’s not really an experiment as much as it is … constructing a blueprint. ***Stimulating
>   the killzone and collecting the resultant patterns***. Putting them all together to achieve the greatest
>   breakthrough in the history of science and medicine.
>
> *The Scorch Trials by James Dashner*

This area is what is stimulated in the elaborate experiment with stress and pleasure known as [The Trials](http://mazerunner.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trials). The extreme and carefully monitored stress in the maze is needed to provoke the brain patterns that make the Gladers inmune to the Flare.

> “***These situations inflicted upon you are called the Variables, and each one has been meticulously thought out***.”
>
> “The
>   Maze was a part of the Trials. ***Not one Variable was thrown at you that didn’t serve a purpose for our collection of killzone patterns***. Your escape was part of the Trials. Your battle against the Grievers. The murder of the boy Chuck. The supposed rescue and subsequent trip in the bus. All of it. Part of the Trials.”
>
> *The Scorch Trials by James Dashner*